# Spanish spelling checker for MacVim?

Tags: vim, spell-checking, macvim

How do I add the Spanish spell-checker for MacVim?

I read that this is a useful [link](ftp://ftp.uniovi.es/pub/vim/runtime/spell/ghindex.html), but apparently it is not working ... what should I do?

Comment: go to http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#vimlinks_scripts and download the spanish dictionary

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know about MacVim, however I just tested the following in vim 7.2 on Windows 7.

Set the spelling language to Spanish and switch on spell checking:

```
:set spelllang=es
:set spell
```

At this point Vim tells you:

```
Cannot find spell file for "es" in utf-8. Do you want me to try downloading it?
```

If you say yes, vim will download these two files into the `$VIMRUNTIME/spell` directory:

- http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/es.utf-8.spl
- http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/es.utf-8.sug

Comment: For the suggestions, MacVim gives a warning that it uses 'quite a bit of memory'. Any idea the order of magnitude of that?

Comment: @hodgkin-huxley: `:help spell-remarks` says "Vim does on-the-fly spell checking.  To make this work fast the word list is loaded in memory.  Thus this uses a lot of memory (1 Mbyte or more)". 1MB seems hardly a concern on today's computers.