# MacVim - Switch between languages shortcuts for open file

Tags: vim, locale, macvim

I use MacVim for coding and for my notes.

I write my notes in danish, so i want to be able to change the language of the text in my GUI (not in the menu), so i don't have to watch these: [image].

I read about it and found that you can do `:language help` in MacVim, where you can read that you can change the language and see your locales files by running `locale -a` in the terminal. I found, that `da_DK.UTF-8` was listed.

When i change my language message settings with `:lan mes da_DK.UTF-8` it switches, but my text in the current file is still underlined with the red error line.

If i open a new file the language is danish, but i want to be able to change it on the fly.

**How to do this?**

---

I tried:

Running `:e` without a filename as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim) where they talk about refreshing to read a config file - but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out learning from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778016/spanish-spelling-checker-for-macvim)!

You can put a language in your `~/.vim/spell/` folder.

For danish:

http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/da.utf-8.spl

http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/da.utf-8.sug

And then in MacVim you can change language by calling `:set spelllang=da` **!!!**

---

Note:

You can (of course) make a shortcut in your .vimrc file:

```
" Set english and danish spelling easy
nmap <Leader>da :set spelllang=da<CR>
nmap <Leader>en :set spelllang=en<CR>
```

Comment: You can also use multiple languages, e.g. `:set spellang=en_us,da`. See `:h 'spelllang'` for more information

Comment: And if you want it in your `.vimrc` you can set: `setglobal spell spelllang=en,da`